# Graph of an advanced function (hard level)

Tags: overleaf, graphs, pgfmath, engineering, function

I have to do on overleaf the graph of this function:

[image]

fo is =1. "w" is the variable and it's=angle/T so we don't need to know T. The final graph is:
[image]

N.B. When w=0 G(w) it's = Tfo because we derived the function:

[image]

and the limit is:

[image]

can someone help me to plot the graph? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/) .

Comment: (unrelated) use `\sin` for the sine function.

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? This is quite straightforward to do with `pgfplots`: https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?lang=en.  You have a nice gallery of examples at https://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/ also. Just start plotting from 0.01 and add the last point manually if you have precision problem at w=0.

Comment: Do you want to plot the function `G(x) = sin(a*x)/x` for some `a`? It's very hard to read the question tbh

Comment: @MichaelFraiman I want to plot the function G(w) = sin (T w/2)/(w/2). But I don't know how to do it 'cause I have to write it down. First of all i've to tell the program that w=angle/T so on the x axis we will have a variation of the angle (and consequently of the w) and that for w=0 the g(w) is T (*fo).

Comment: So it seems that `G(w) = 2sin(T* w/2)/w = 2Tsin(a/2)/a`. Correct?

Comment: @MichaelFraiman correct.

Comment: Then it seems that half of your question is irrelevant and you just want to plot `sin(x/2)/x`

Comment: @FrancescoF96, have a look at this section in the pgfmanual https://tikz.dev/dv-visualizers, which shows you several ways to do it.